# select2 create tag if is not in dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I'm sorry I looked over the documentation and searched other examples and I can not figure it out.. I want to check if the entered value exists in dropdown and if not, to add it to the dropdown and save it in database with ajax. Because the function is triggered onchange (when I hit enter), the tag is added to the dropdown and the ajax is not entered. I have tried to change the even to oninput/onkeyup and i also tried '$(".selectType").on("select2:select", function(event)'.

HTML

```
<div class="col-md-6 ">
            <label class="form-label">Type <span class="required">*</span></label> <br>
            <select class="selectType" name="project_types[]" multiple="multiple" style="height: 200px; width: 100%;" onchange="handleCustomType(this)">
                <?php
                if (!empty($types)) {
                    foreach ($types as $type) {
                        echo '<option value="' . $type->ID . '">' . $type->name . '</option>';
                    }
                }
                ?>
            </select>
        </div>
```

JS

```
    $(".selectType").select2({
    tags: true,
});


function handleCustomType(selectElement) { console.log('kkt');
        const customTypeValue = selectElement.value;

        if (customTypeValue.trim() === '') {
            console.log('kk');
            return;
          }
console.log(Array.from(selectElement.options));
        const isInDropdown = Array.from(selectElement.options).some(option => option.value === customTypeValue);

        if (!isInDropdown) {
        console.log('isnot')
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: base_url + 'projects/addCustomType',
                data: {
                  type: customTypeValue
                },
                success: function(response) {
                  if (response.status == 'success') {

                    const newOption = new Option(customTypeValue, response.typeID, true, true);
                    $(selectElement).append(newOption).trigger('change');
                  } else {
                    console.error('Error saving custom type:', response.message);
                  }
                },
                error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                  console.error('AJAX Error:', error);
                }
            });
        }

    }
```

Thank you!

Comment: https://select2.org/programmatic-control/add-select-clear-items this is the library I am using

Comment: I don't get it. The user selects an option in a select element and then you test if the option is in the same select element and if not, you do a AJAX request -- that doesn't make sense. Or are you talking about two different select elements?